# Is there a way to automatically translate position of vertices to normalize to 0-1?

Tags: vertices, scale

I mean every vertex position should be between 0-1.

I use Monogame so I can't use scaling (button <kbd>S</kbd>). I decided to make a model which would have vertices position between 0-1 and then scale it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean, that every x-, y- and z-coordinate of every vertex in your mesh should have a value between 0 and 1? If yes, here's the solution (fully in the 3D Viewport):

1. with your Mesh selected in object mode apply the scale of your model (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> then click `Scale`)
2. set the origin to be at the center of the bounds of the object: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, then click `Origin to Geometry`, hit <kbd>F6</kbd> and choose in the Menu after `Center:` `Bounds Center`
3. open the properties shelf on the right <kbd>N</kbd>
4. you see a panel called `Transform`. In this panel you see a property called `Dimensions:`. choose the largest value of the three and change it to $1$.
5. under `Scale:` one of the three $1.00000$ will have changed. Copy that value by hovering over it and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>
6. Paste it over all other $1.00000$ in `Scale:` (hovering over the value again and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>)
7. Under `Location:` set every entry to $0.5$ (you can set the first and copy-paste it like explained before.)
8. Your Mesh now fits perfectly into the box from 0 to 1 on all axis. Lastly you can set the origin if you want to $(0,0,0)$, which may be useful for Monogame later. Do this by applying the location of your model (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> then click `Location`)
9. Additionally you can apply the scale, but that's depending on what Monogame requires. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> then click `Scale`)

Comment: Should the scale be applied, too?

Comment: Good question. I don't know. Is it necessary for monogame?

Comment: I can't imagine it does any harm ; )

Comment: Agree with @RobinBetts that scale needs to be applied. Without you are scaling the object to fit in global coordinate unit cube. Which IMO makes no sense, eg the default cube will still have vertex coordinate (-1, -1, -1). And if used as an asset elsewhere will be 2 x 2 x 2.  By applying transform and scale you make sure the mesh is always contained in a unit cube locally, and globally when  when its object is scaled to unity

Answer (score 0):

**Vert coordinates normalized to [0, 1]**

If I understand the question, you want to limit the `x, y, z` of a vertex's local coordinate to the range [0, 1]

[image]
*Result after running on default cube*

Script below takes all selected mesh objects and normalizes the mesh coordinates, by placing the origin at the bounding box (FBL) corner, and re-scaling the blender object to match. Run in object mode.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from math import sqrt
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector

sqrt3 = sqrt(3)

context = bpy.context

meshobs = [o for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH']

bm = bmesh.new()
for o in meshobs:
    bbox = [Vector(b) for b in o.bound_box]
    origin = bbox[0]

    global_origin = o.matrix_world * origin
    diag = bbox[6] - origin
    if diag.length < 0.0001: # single vert?
        continue
    bm.from_mesh(o.data)
    # downscale if needed
    scale_factor = 1 if diag.length < sqrt3 else sqrt3 / diag.length
    # transform verts
    matrix = scale_factor * Matrix.Translation(-origin)
    bmesh.ops.transform(bm, matrix=matrix, verts=bm.verts)
    bm.to_mesh(o.data)
    bm.clear()
    o.matrix_world.translation = global_origin

    o.scale *= 1 / scale_factor
bm.free()
```

Comment: The cube in the picture looks like if its vertices are in $[0,2]$ on all axes. Am I wrong?

Comment: @quiliup  As clearly stated in answer. The local coordinates of all the vertices of the cube are set in range  [0, 1].  Vertex coordinates are always in local coordinates. In the image the  cube is scaled by 2 to match default cube proportions. AFAIK monogame requires neither global nor local coordinate systems to be normalized. Only UVs.  Cheers for heads up on why the  DV.